# IndexError: list index out of range when composing dict from 2 column csv

Tags: python

My script that crunches numbers stored in csv gets the numbers into a dict from the csv like this:

```
fide_rating_file = fide_csv_rating_file.read()
fide_rating_file = fide_rating_file.split("\n")
fide_rating_file2 = [f for f in fide_rating_file if len(f) > 0]
fide_rating_file3 = [f.split(",") for f in fide_rating_file2]
fide_ratings = {f[0]: f[1] for f in fide_rating_file3}
```

This is probably not a pythonic way to work with csv (suggestions are welcome), I succesfully ran the script on tens of csv files. Now I am getting a traceback telling me that:

```
File "...script.py", line 76, in script
fide_ratings = {f[0]: f[1] for f in fide_rating_file3}
File "...script.py", line 76, in <dictcomp>
fide_ratings = {f[0]: f[1] for f in fide_rating_file3}
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The csv looks like this (this is just an excerpt, is way too long to post here):

```
1701991,2383
1407589,2188
1401815,2451
1411802,1913
1406248,2068
504599,2134
2252465,2099
```

The fact that it ran without errors on other files would suggest that this particular csv is corrupted. I checked for all inconsistencies I thought of compared to the rest of the files and found none. Thats why I am asking about the script here.

Comment: you may have stumbled on an empty line or a line with only 1 field. Also use the `csv` module, much better.

Comment: It simply means you have at least *one* case where `f.split(',')` returned only one element, so a line that doesn't have a comma in it.

Comment: You are re-inventing the CSV parsing wheel here. Use `dict(csv.reader(fide_csv_rating_file)))`  instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only get a sublist containing at least two items iff, there is a comma on every line

```
fide_rating_file3 = [f.split(",") for f in fide_rating_file2]
#                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You may test for the presence of commas before splitting or clean out lines without commas in the pre-processing stage:

```
fide_rating_file = [f.strip().split(",") for f in fide_csv_rating_file if ',' in f]
fide_ratings = {f[0]: f[1] for f in fide_rating_file}
```

On another note, it would be better if your actually used the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module from the standard library for parsing your file content.

Answer (score 0):

Per everyones advice I used the standard library csv module

```
dict(csv.reader(fide_csv_rating_file))
```

Following error traceback pointed me to the incorrect lines, just removed them with regex find and replace and then succesfully created the dict.

Thanks guys.